# If $a_1 I_n \leq A \leq a_2 I_n$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $a_1,a_2$ are positive scalars. Then what can I say about $A$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

I have, 
\begin{equation}
a_1 I_n \leq A \leq a_2 I_n
\end{equation}
where, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $a_1,a_2$ are positive scalars. Then can be say that $A$ is a Positive definite matrix?
I have developed a rudimentary proof:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_1x^T I_n x& \leq x^T A x \leq a_2 x^T I_n x \\
a_1\|x\|^2 & \leq x^T A x \leq a_2\|x\|^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is any vector.
Now looking at the last equation, and using the fact that $a_1,a_2 \geq 0$, can we claim that $A$ is PD?

Comment: What does $\leq$ mean here?

Comment: @Matt I have edited my question, please check again. $\leq$ means smaller than or equal to.

Comment: **If** you are using $A \le B$ to mean $B - A$ is positive semidefinite, the result is trivially true.  If you mean each matrix element of $A$ is less than or equal to the corresponding matrix element of $B$, then it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $A\le B$ implies $x^HAx\le x^HBx$ for all $x$, by means of the definitory inequality $x^H(B-A)x\ge 0$.

Comment: I have also attached the brief outline of my rudimentary proof. Can you comment if my steps were correct. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: That is contained in what I've already written.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my rudimentary proof! Thanks once again!